# Do we really need 1s complement?

Tags: math, binary, error-correction, error-detection, data-communication

Why do we actually need 1s compliment?

Can we simply make a number negative or positive by by just flipping one bit!
the MSB bit?
Why do we need to flip all bits

Comment: "Flipping just one bit" is essentially equivalent to representation commonly referred to as sign-magnitude. It's perfectly reasonable and is often used to represent arbitrary precision integers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, `1s complement`, `2s complement` or `sign-magnitude` (flipping the MS bit) can all be useful. [There is no definitive criterion by which any of the representations is universally superior.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

To answer your question, `1s complement` can be better than `sign-magnitude` when you are performing arithmetic operations. You would need different hardware for addition and subtraction when using `sign-magnitude`; but you can use the same hardware for both operations when using `1s complement` (i.e., addition is addition, subtraction is addition with complement).